# Узнать символ из строки C#

Tags: c#, строки, char, index

Как имея строку, например:
string a="яблоко"
провести операцию с каким-либо символом из этого слова? Например:

```
if(символ 1 = "я")
{
//Действие
}
```

Comment: `if(a[0] == 'я')` Документация: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8#strings-and-indexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По индексу:

```
if(a[0] == 'я')
```

> Индекс — это неотрицательное, отсчитываемое от нуля число, которое начинается от первой позиции в строке, что равно нулевой позиции индекса.

PS По поводу "произвести операцию" с символом: обратите внимание, что строки в C# иммутабельны, то есть их изменить нельзя! (Если нужно изменять строку - то это достигается созданием новой строки) В остальном же - сравнивайте с буквой "я" или делайте остальные операции как вам нравится.

Документация: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8#strings-and-indexes